# Evaluate a BitVec in Z3Py

Tags: expression, z3py, evaluate

I am learning Z3 and perhaps my question does not apply, so please be patient.

Suppose I have the following:

```
c1, c2 = z3.BitVec('c1', 32), z3.BitVec('c2', 32)

c1 = c1 + c1
c2 = c2 + c2
c2 = c2 + c1
c1 = c1 + c2

e1 = z3.simplify(c1)
e2 = z3.simplify(c2)
```

When I print their sexpr():

```
print "e1=", e1.sexpr()
print "e2=", e2.sexpr()

Output:

e1= (bvadd (bvmul #x00000004 c1) (bvmul #x00000002 c2))
e2= (bvadd (bvmul #x00000002 c2) (bvmul #x00000002 c1))
```

My question is, how can I evaluate the numerical value of 'e1' and 'e2' for user supplied values of c1 and c2?

For example, e1(c1=1, c2=1) == 6, e2(c1=1, c2=1) == 4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to introduce two separate variables that will hold the expressions. Then I had to introduce two result variables for which I can query the model for their value:

```
e1, e2, c1, c2, r1, r2 = z3.BitVec('e1', 32), z3.BitVec('e2', 32), z3.BitVec('c1', 32), 
                         z3.BitVec('c2', 32), z3.BitVec('r1', 32), z3.BitVec('r2', 32)

e1 = c1
e2 = c2

e1 = e1 + e1
e2 = e2 + e2
e2 = e2 + e1
e1 = e1 + e2

e1 = z3.simplify(e1)
e2 = z3.simplify(e2)

print "e1=", e1
print "e2=", e2

s = z3.Solver()

s.add(c1 == 5, c2 == 1, e1 == r1, e2 == r2)
if s.check() == z3.sat:
    m = s.model()
    print 'r1=', m[r1].as_long()
    print 'r2=', m[r2].as_long()
```

Comment: In general your coding style is somewhat confusing to me. it seems that it would be easier to use new python variables for new expressions, so that each variable holds one particular assignment (like in Single Static Assignments).
You can then more easily track changes.
Hence I would advise against re-using variables (as you do with e1 and e2 repeatedly)

Comment: @stklik this code is an example. In the real case, the expressions 'e1' and 'e2' are updated in a loop based on disassembled instructions (200+ of ADD/SUB/INC/DEC instructions). At the end of the loop, we get the final expressions. We replace c1 and c2 with their values to compute the simplified expression from 200+ instructions.